# NSURLSessionでの認証

Tags: ios, objective-c

Objective-Cを使いBittrexのAPI認証をしたいと思いこちらを参考にして  https://bittrex.com/home/api 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610874/bittrex-api-returns-apikey-not-provided

以下のようなコードを書きました。

```
- (void)fetch {

  double unixtime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];


  NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:@"https://bittrex.com"];
  components.path = @"/api/v1.1/account/getbalances";


  NSURLQueryItem *nonce  = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"nonce"  value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",unixtime]];
  NSURLQueryItem *apikey = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"apikey" value:@"xxxxx"];
  components.queryItems = @[nonce,apikey];
  NSURL *url = [components URL];


  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                     timeoutInterval:10.0];




  [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
  [request setValue:[self sha512:components.query withSalt:@"xxxxx"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"apisign"];
  NSData *body = [components.query dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
  [request setHTTPBody:body];



  [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                   completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                     if (response && ! error) {
                                         NSLog(@"%@",  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]);
                                     } else {
                                         NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                     }

                                 }] resume];





}
```

しかしこのメッセージが返ってきてしまいます。

```
{
    message = "APIKEY_NOT_PROVIDED";
    result = "<null>";
    success = 0;
}
```

APIの認証などは今までほとんどやったことがなく困っています。どのように書いたらいいのでしょうか？

Comment: 上記コードを私の環境で試したところ `APIKEY_INVALID` が返ってきました。。謎ですね

Comment: ちなみに `[request setHTTPBody:bo**strong text**dy];` の行は必要でしょうか？

Comment: bo**strong text**dyの部分は間違いなので修正しました。API認証自体ほとんどやったことがない為どこまであっているかも自分でわかっていません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[公式ドキュメント](https://bittrex.com/home/api)にあるように、apisign ヘッダを作る際はクエリだけでなく、URLまるごとSHA512のハッシュにするようです。

つまり、

```
[request setValue:[self sha512:components.query withSalt:@"xxxxx"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"apisign"];
```

ではなく、

```
[request setValue:[self sha512:url.absoluteString withSalt:@"xxxxx"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"apisign"];
```

とするのが正しいです。

また、

```
NSData *body = [components.query dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

の2行は不要です。

Comment: ご指摘通りに変更したら成功しました。また、英語版の方にもご回答いただきありがとうございました。

Comment: @tsnmi  お役に立てて嬉しいです。この質問はまだ「未解決」状態になっているので、解決した場合は回答の承認をお願い致します
 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers